# Mongoose find array with $in

Tags: arrays, node.js, mongodb, mongoose

```
Team.find({
        '_id': { $in: [
            teamIds
        ] }
    }, function(err, teamData) {
        console.log("teams name  " + teamData);
    });
```

This code gives us undefined back.. But in the var teamIds is this:

```
545646d5f5c1cce828982eb7,
545646d5f5c1cce828982eb8,
54564af5c9ddf61e2b56ad1e,
54564c1f1de201782bcdb623,
54564d2fc660a7e12be6c7a2,
54564df985495f142c638f9f,
54564eadb511f1792c9be138,
54564ec40cf6708a2cd01c81,
54564ee495f4aea22cf23728
```

Does anybody see the error?

Answer (score 49, accepted):

If `teamIds` is already an array, then you shouldn't wrap it in another array:

```
Team.find({
    '_id': { $in: teamIds }
}, function(err, teamData) {
    console.log("teams name  " + teamData);
});
```

Or, if `teamIds` is a string of comma-separated id values, you need to convert it into an array of values using `split`:

```
Team.find({
    '_id': { $in: teamIds.split(',') }
}, function(err, teamData) {
    console.log("teams name  " + teamData);
});
```

Comment: Would `_id` not in quotes work? `Team.find({ _id: { &in: teamIds } })`

Comment: @Pete yes "_" and "$" are legal variable chars.

Answer (score 0):

This will remove spaces in comma-separated values:

```
Team.find({
  '_id': { $in: teamIds.replace(/\s/g, "").split(',') }}, function(err, teamData) {
    console.log("teams name  " + teamData);
});
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).