# Returns only 1 find document but I request 3 ids to find node/express

Tags: node.js, express, mongoose, postman

Why and how am I saving only document from find query when I pass 3 ids?

[image]

I wanted to get from that loop what will return

```
router.post("/addBand", async (req, res) => {
  let singers = req.body.singer

  let singerArr = singers.split(', ')

  let singer
  for (let i = 0; i < singerArr.length; i++) {
    // solo = await GroupBand.findOne({ singer: ObjectId(singerArr[i]) }).populate('singer')
    singer = await Singer.find({ _id: ObjectId(singerArr[i]) })
    console.log(1, singer);
  }

  console.log(2, singer);

  const addedGroup = new GroupBand({
    bandName: req.body.bandName,
    singer: singer, // [...singer],
    debutDate: Date.parse(req.body.debutDate)
  })

  console.log(3, addedGroup);
  return
```

But it seems like the only one get is from the last id I request. I also tried the spread operator incase it might need to just spread its value, but I get singer is not iterable

```
1 [ { createdAt: 2019-11-16T05:43:43.971Z,
    updatedAt: null,
    deletedAt: null,
    assignedAt: null,
    _id: 5dcf8c8fef739a6159938ca8,
    name: 'KyuHyun',
    __v: 0 } ]
1 [ { createdAt: 2019-11-16T05:48:51.194Z,
    updatedAt: null,
    deletedAt: null,
    assignedAt: null,
    _id: 5dcf8dc320742961c8b5a801,
    name: 'Yesung',
    __v: 0 } ]
1 [ { createdAt: 2019-11-16T05:53:14.469Z,
    updatedAt: null,
    deletedAt: null,
    assignedAt: null,
    _id: 5dcf8eca20742961c8b5a808,
    name: 'Ryewook',
    __v: 0 } ]
2 { createdAt: 2019-11-16T05:53:14.469Z,
  updatedAt: null,
  deletedAt: null,
  assignedAt: null,
  _id: 5dcf8eca20742961c8b5a808,
  name: 'Ryewook',
  __v: 0 }
3 { createdAt: null,
  updatedAt: null,
  deletedAt: null,
  assignedAt: null,
  _id: 5dda2fb9e69e6c22d429bbd9,
  bandName: 'Super Junior - K.R.Y',
  singer:
   [ { createdAt: 2019-11-16T05:53:14.469Z,
       updatedAt: null,
       deletedAt: null,
       assignedAt: null,
       _id: 5dcf8eca20742961c8b5a808,
       name: 'Ryewook',
       __v: 0 } ],
  debutDate: 2006-11-04T16:00:00.000Z }
```

Comment: Can you try to send data in raw JSON like this? https://ibb.co/7VdjW4C

Comment: I still get the same value in raw JSON

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this

```
  let singerArr = singers.split(', ')
  let singerArrayId=singerArr.map(ele=>ObjectId(ele)) or //  let singerArrayId=singerArr.map(ele=>mongoose.Types.ObjectId(ele))
  let data=await Singer.find({'_id': { $in:singerArrayId }});
```

Answer (score 0):

You should use the &in operator to retrieve more than one documents from your db.

There is an example of use [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26701096/mongoose-find-array-with-in/26701186)

EDIT

Try this without the for loop :

```
singer = await Singer.find({ _id : $in: singerArr }})
```

This should do the trick as $in operator take an array of ids as argument.

Comment: Tried but it is still the same

Comment: Can you post the value of singerArr and also the find query with the $in operator please ?

Answer (score 0):

[image]
After I got the result from split I loop them to pass on Singer document and find their ids